# Modificar datos de una listbox en python con tkinter usando postgresql...mouseEvent

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, postgresql, tkinter

tengo una interfaz en donde muestro con una Listbox una serie de datos de diferentes clientes. me preguntaba si es posible seleccionar un dato de ahí y que se pueda modificar directamente?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esos son los datos que tengo en postgresql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y aquí por ejemplo, selecciono la opción de teléfono y que esta opción aparezca en el Entry para solo modificar y que en postgresql se haga un update.
antes solía programar en java y recuerdo hacer esto:

```
JButton btnModificar = new JButton("Actualizar");
    btnModificar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String [] registro= {textTitulo.getText(),textProductora.getText(),textArtista.getText(),textPrecio.getText(), textCodigo.getText()};
            int opcion= actualizarRegistros(registro);
            if(opcion != 0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro Actualizado");
                FormularioDiscos volver=new FormularioDiscos();
                volver.setVisible(true);
                Discos.this.dispose();
            }
        }
    });
```

y la funcion de actualizarRegistros():

```
public static int actualizarRegistros(String [] dato){
    int result = 0;
    String sql = "UPDATE \"Disco\" SET "
            + "\"Titulo\"='"+dato[0]+"', \"Productora\"='"+dato[1]+"', "
            + "\"Artista\"='"+dato[2]+"', "
            + "\"Precio\"='"+dato[3]+"',\"Codigo\"='"+dato[4]+"'WHERE \"Codigo\" = '"+dato[4]+"'";
    conectar();
    try {
        sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
        result=sentencia.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
```

mas no se bien que hacer en el caso de un actionListener o actionPerformed en python, es esto posible? es permitido desde una listbox?
entiendo que existe un modulo llamado pymouse, pero no pude instalarlo, tuve problemas...este modulo me ayudaría?

esto es lo del modulo Cliente, el que quiero modificar:

```
from tkinter import *
import psycopg2
import sys
import pprint
import Base_de_datos
#import Base_de_datos 
#import MergeSort

class Cliente:
    def __init__(self,codigoTarjeta=None,nombre=None,telefono=None,direccion=None,edad=None):
        self.codigoTarjeta=codigoTarjeta
        self.nombre=nombre
        self.telefono=telefono
        self.direccion=direccion
        self.edad=edad

    def ingresar(self):
        self.ventanaIngresar= Toplevel()
        self.ventanaIngresar.geometry("570x400")
        self.ventanaIngresar.title("Cliente")
        img = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/checo/Desktop/Casino3.png")
        imagen= Label(self.ventanaIngresar,image=img)
        imagen.pack()
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Cliente",background="LavenderBlush",font=("Cambria",14)).place(x=5,y=0)
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Codigo de tarjeta: ",background="LavenderBlush",font=("Cambria",11)).place(x=0,y=30)
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Nombre: ",background="LavenderBlush",font=("Cambria",11)).place(x=0,y=60)
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Telefono: ",background="LavenderBlush",font=("Cambria",11)).place(x=0,y=90)
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Direccion: ",background="LavenderBlush",font=("Cambria",11)).place(x=0,y=120)
        Label(self.ventanaIngresar, text="Edad: ",background="LavenderBlush",font=("Cambria",11)).place(x=0,y=150)

        self.codigoTarjeta=StringVar()
        Entry(self.ventanaIngresar, textvariable=self.codigoTarjeta).place(x=120,y=30)
        self.nombre=StringVar()
        Entry(self.ventanaIngresar, textvariable=self.nombre).place(x=65,y=60)
        self.telefono=StringVar()
        Entry(self.ventanaIngresar, textvariable=self.telefono).place(x=70,y=90)
        self.direccion=StringVar()
        Entry(self.ventanaIngresar, textvariable=self.direccion).place(x=75,y=120)
        self.edad=StringVar()
        Entry(self.ventanaIngresar, textvariable=self.edad).place(x=50,y=150)

        Button(self.ventanaIngresar,text="Guardar",background="FireBrick",font=("Cambria",11),
                   width=15,command=self.BD).place(x=420,y=5)

        Button(self.ventanaIngresar,text="Modificar",background="FireBrick",font=("Cambria",11),
                   width=15).place(x=420,y=365)

        Button(self.ventanaIngresar,text="Mostrar",background="FireBrick",font=("Cambria",11),
                     width=15,command=self.Mostrar).place(x=0,y=365)

        Button(self.ventanaIngresar,text="Eliminar",background="FireBrick",font=("Cambria",11),
                     width=15,command=self.Eliminar).place(x=220,y=365)

        self.ventanaIngresar.mainloop()
    def BD(self):
        conectar=Base_de_datos.BaseDeDatos()
        comando="INSERT INTO public.Cliente("'"codigoTarjeta"'", nombre, telefono, direccion, edad) VALUES('"+self.codigoTarjeta.get()+"','"+self.nombre.get()+"','"+self.telefono.get()+"','"+self.direccion.get()+"','"+self.edad.get()+"')"
        comando2="INSERT INTO public.Recarga("'"idCliente"'",saldo2) VALUES('"+self.codigoTarjeta.get()+"', 0 )"
        print(comando)
        conectar.cursor.execute(comando)
        conectar.cursor.execute(comando2)
    def Mostrar(self):
        comando="SELECT * FROM cliente;"
        conectar=Base_de_datos.BaseDeDatos()
        conectar.cursor.execute(comando)
        Scroll=Scrollbar(self.ventanaIngresar, orient=VERTICAL)
        self.listbox=Listbox(self.ventanaIngresar, font=("Cambria",9), background="LavenderBlush", borderwidth=0, yscrollcommand=Scroll.set,height=12,relief="sunken",width=78)
        self.listbox.place(x=5, y=180)
        Scroll.config(command=self.listbox.yview)
        Scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        for dato1, dato2 in enumerate(conectar.cursor.fetchall()):
            self.listbox.insert(0, "Codigo de Tarjeta: {}".format(dato2[0]))
            self.listbox.insert(1, "Nombre: {}".format(dato2[1]))
            self.listbox.insert(2, "Telefono: {}".format(dato2[2]))
            self.listbox.insert(3, "Direccion: {}".format(dato2[3]))
            self.listbox.insert(4, "Edad: {}".format(dato2[4]))
            self.listbox.insert(5, " ")
    def Eliminar(self):
        self.palabra=None
        self.ventanaEliminar=Toplevel()
        self.ventanaEliminar.geometry("265x298")
        self.ventanaEliminar.title("Eliminar")
        Label(self.ventanaEliminar, text="Codigo del cliente",font=("Calibri Light",14)).place(x=5,y=0)
        self.palabra=StringVar()
        Entry(self.ventanaEliminar, textvariable=self.palabra).place(x=70,y=30)
        Button(self.ventanaEliminar,text="Buscar",font=("Cambria",11),
                   width=10,command=self.Buscar).place(x=85,y=60)
    def Buscar(self):          
        comando="SELECT * FROM cliente where "'"codigoTarjeta"'"='"+self.palabra.get()+"';"
        conectar=Base_de_datos.BaseDeDatos()
        conectar.cursor.execute(comando) 
        self.listbox=Listbox(self.ventanaEliminar, font=("Cambria",9), background="LavenderBlush", borderwidth=0,height=10,relief="sunken",width=35)
        self.listbox.place(x=5, y=90)
        for dato1, dato2 in enumerate(conectar.cursor.fetchall()):
            self.listbox.insert(0, "Codigo de Tarjeta: {}".format(dato2[0]))
            self.listbox.insert(1, "Nombre: {}".format(dato2[1]))
            self.listbox.insert(2, "Telefono: {}".format(dato2[2]))
            self.listbox.insert(3, "Direccion: {}".format(dato2[3]))
            self.listbox.insert(4, "Edad: {}".format(dato2[4]))
            self.listbox.insert(5, " ")
        Button(self.ventanaEliminar,text="Eliminar",font=("Cambria",11),
                width=10, command=self.Eliminacion).place(x=85,y=240)
    def Eliminacion(self):
        self.ventanaEliminar.destroy()
        comando="DELETE FROM cliente where "'"codigoTarjeta"'"='"+self.palabra.get()+"';"
        conectar=Base_de_datos.BaseDeDatos()
        conectar.cursor.execute(comando)
        self.ventanaMensaje=Toplevel()
        self.ventanaMensaje.geometry("210x80")
        self.ventanaMensaje.title("Eliminar")
        Label(self.ventanaMensaje, text="LISTO!! Registro eliminado",font=("Calibri Light",14)).place(x=5,y=10)
```

Comment: Hola, @Gonzo30. Te podríamos ayudar mejor si pusieras el código python en tkinter que hayas probado. En general, para Tk, puedes interceptar los eventos `<<ListboxSelect>>` de un `Listbox`. Lamentablemente, no está documentado en Tkinter. Tendrás que buscar en la documetnación de TCL/Tk que es el lenguaje que usa internamente Tkinter: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/morewidgets.html

Comment: @ChemaCortes agregue código del modulo que estoy usando. De hecho busque información en un libro que solo habla de TKinter y no encontré nada, revisaré eso que me has mandado...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te ponía en el comentario, tienes que interceptar el evento `<<ListboxSelect>>`. El código que has puesto es demasiado extenso. Deberías haber puesto un ejemplo mínimo y reproducible, tal como se recomienda en las normas del foro.

Te pongo un ejemplo corto de cómo se haría:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class ListWidget(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root, valores):

        self.valores = valores

        super().__init__(root)

        lstvar = StringVar(self, value=valores)
        self.lst = Listbox(self, listvariable=lstvar)
        self.lst.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.seleccion)
        self.lst.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

        s = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.lst.yview)
        self.lst["yscrollcommand"] = s.set
        s.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=(N, S))

        self.entryVar = StringVar(self, value='Pulsa un valor')
        self.entry = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entryVar)
        self.entry.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

    def seleccion(self, *args):
        idxs = self.lst.curselection()
        if len(idxs) == 1:
            idx = int(idxs[0])
            self.lst.see(idx)
            self.entryVar.set(self.valores[idx])


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # ejemplo de datos
    DATOS = sum(([f"nombre{i}",f"telefono{i}"] for i in range(100)),[])

    root = Tk()
    lst = ListWidget(root, DATOS)
    lst.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ya me quedo un poco más claro y creo que ya se como hacerle, gracias :)